# Is it possible to register jobs from existing batch metadata tables

Tags: spring-batch

We're trying to create a UI screen which will be able to trigger spring batch jobs and use our existing database with job execution records.

I was able to get all existing `jobNames` via `jobExplorer` but now I get an error on `jobRegistry.getJob(jobName)`.
 It seems the jobs are not registered in `jobRegistry`.

The actual configuration of the jobs is placed in another application. 
I try to trigger the job from another application (solely for batch related functions - runJob, stopJob, view executions, etc).

EDIT:
Is it possible to be able to register the jobs to `JobRegistry` from existing batch metadata tables? - *What I mean by this is that the jobs and step beans would be recreated from existing metadata tables.*

What we did for a workaround is that execution records can be retrieved using the metadata tables but the runJob, stopJob functions would need to be redirected to exposed endpoints of the batch job applications.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "register jobs from existing batch metadata tables", but you might need a custom `JobLocator`.

Comment: I am facing same issue, got any solution for above one pls..?