# spring batch error NoSuchJobException: No such job (either in registry or in historical data)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch. I am trying to write a code to run uncompleted jobs.  I am actually getting **below error:**

> org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No such
> job (either in registry or in historical data)

**Below is the code I've tried, could anyone please tell me what went wrong below?**

```
void restartUncompletedJobs() {
        try {
            String jobName = "job1";
            
            Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(jobName); //HERE GETTING EXCEPTION

            List<Long> jobInstances = jobOperator.getJobInstances(job.getName(), 0, 5);
            for (Long jobInstanceId : jobInstances) {

                Set<Long> jobRunningExecutions = jobOperator.getRunningExecutions(jobName);
                
                if (jobRunningExecutions.size() > 0) {
                    jobOperator.startNextInstance(jobName);
                } else {
                    jobOperator.restart(jobInstanceId);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: anyone has any idea on above?

Comment: I am facing similar issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610787/is-it-possible-to-register-jobs-from-existing-batch-metadata-tables , not finding any answer for this..

Comment: Still looking for a solution.. any idea on above pls?

Comment: Where do we need to plug this code , so that job automatically restarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to populate the registry yourself or register a [JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#jobregistrybeanpostprocessor) in your application context to populate all jobs in the registry.

Comment: I already tried using Bean JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor, even still facing same issue.. If you dont mind, can you pls try above snippet and paste me working code..BTW, I am using Spring Boot only..

Comment: you can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/8762e3411557aaf887867f8d8594b01127538cb1/spring-batch-core/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/test-environment-with-registry-and-auto-register.xml